# How to skip .hg / .git / .svn directories while recursing tree in python

Tags: python, directory, os.walk

I have a python script which I have been piecing together (one of my first python forays).

The script recurses a folder looking for XCode project files; the script works fine, but I would like to adapt it to skip any .svn (or .hg or .git) folders so that it isn't trying to modify source repositories.

Here is the script for the recursive search

```
for root, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):
    files = [f for f in files if re.search("project\.pbxproj", f)]
    for f in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, f)
        print "Adjusting BaseSDK for %s" % (filename)
        ...
```

How can I exclude the repository sub-trees?

Comment: Did you look at the os.walk documentation?  http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk.  The exact solution is in the documentation.  `dirnames.remove(".svn")`

Comment: Just came across here as i wanted to delete all .svn files in a project, the command [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) just does this without the need for a script (in hg & git there is just one folder in the root of the project you have to delete).

Comment: @S.Lott Thank you for pointing out the spot in documentation; not sure why I missed it before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As S.Lott says in his comment, this is mentioned in the documentation for `os.walk`. The following should work fine:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    if ".hg" in dirs:
        dirs.remove(".hg")
    for f in files:
        print os.path.join(root, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before handling the file, you can check if the first character in the filename begins with a ".", if it does, continue to the next item in the loop.

```
for root, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):
    files = [f for f in files if re.search("project\.pbxproj", f)]
    for f in files:
        ### EDIT START
        if f[0] == ".":
            continue
        ### EDIT FINISH

        filename = os.path.join(root, f)
        print "Adjusting BaseSDK for %s" % (filename)
```

Comment: .hg, .git, .svn are folders. Also see the comment in question above.